# Calculate the mean value of symmetry data in a matrix with R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like this :

```
A = matrix( 
  c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 4, 5, 1), # the data elements 
  nrow=3,              # number of rows 
  ncol=3,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE
)     

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    3
[2,]    1    5    7
[3,]    4    5    1
```

Now I want to calculate the mean value of symmetry data in this matrix, just like this :

```
> A.mean
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0  2.5  3.5
[2,]  2.5  5.0  6.0
[3,]  3.5  6.0  1.0
```

How can I do this without using loop？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try:

```
(A+t(A))/2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  2.0  2.5  3.5
#[2,]  2.5  5.0  6.0
#[3,]  3.5  6.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, list(A, t(A)))/2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  2.0  2.5  3.5
#[2,]  2.5  5.0  6.0
#[3,]  3.5  6.0  1.0
```